# How can I get the result of a stored procedure in C#?

Tags: c#, sql, database, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

Here is my code in C#:

```
float r_discountValue = 0;

SqlConnection con = Constant.GetConnection();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Coupon_GetDiscountFromValidCouponCode", con);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@PKCouponCode", SqlDbType.VarChar);
cmd.Parameters["@PKCouponCode"].Value = "DIS_77";

try
{
    con.Open();

    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    if(reader.Read()){
       r_discountValue = float.Parse(reader[0].ToString());
    }

    reader.Close();
}
catch(Exception exception)
{
    throw exception;
}
finally{
    con.Close();
}

return r_discountValue;
```

The stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Coupon_GetDiscountFromValidCouponCode]
    @PKCouponCode varchar(50)
AS
    SELECT * 
    FROM Coupon 
    WHERE CouponCode = @PKCouponCode AND Valid = 1
```

Here is how the DB looks like:

[image]

I encounter an error

> Input string was not in a correct format

I don't know what's thing is going wrong, any ideas?

Comment: can you plz elaborate your actual question in detail? what problem are you facing?

Comment: What is happening with your code? Does it give an error?

Comment: SorrY, I updated my question. `Input string was not in a correct format.` error is occured.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the discount value, then you should return only the discount from the SP (since it **is** named `GetDiscountfrom`...)

```
SELECT CouponDiscount FROM Coupon WHERE CouponCode = @PKCouponCode AND Valid = 1
```

This will make it a one-column resultset, which matches the access `reader[0]` from C#.

The other option is of course to change the C# side to read the second item (index 1) or reference the column by name, e.g.

```
r_discountValue = float.Parse(reader[1].ToString());
r_discountValue = float.Parse(reader["CouponDiscount"].ToString());
```

You would have got `Input string was not in a correct format.` because it was reading "DIS_77" which `float.parse` cannot process.

Answer (score 2):

You are using first column i.e.`CouponCode` for fetching discount. instead of that you need to use second column ie. `couponDiscount`

So try something like this

```
 r_discountValue = float.Parse(reader["CouponDiscount"].ToString());
```